# Как спроектировать базу данных для Laravel?

Tags: laravel, проектирование

Подскажите как спроектировать базу данных станций метро?
Ниже приведена карта метро.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вобщем должен быть поиск расписания по станциям, а также должна быть возможность прокладки маршрута от начальной к конечной станции.
Не совсем понятно, в какой таблице хранить расстояние.
Есть две идеи:

1. хранить расстояния в промежуточной таблице **station_station** (many to many)
2. или хранить в таблице **distances** (one to many)

Первый вариант с помощью промежуточной таблицы station_station (many to many):
**App\Models\Station**:

```
id
name  
type(обычная, пересадка)  
lineName

public function distances()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Station::class);
}
```

**App\Models\StationStation (many to many)**

```
station_id
station_id2
km  (расстояние от station_id до station_id2)
```

И второй вариант хранить расстояние в таблице distances
**App\Models\Station**

```
id
name  
type(обычная, пересадка)  
lineName  

public function distances()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Distance::class);
}
```

**App\Models\Distance**

```
id  
station_id  
station_id2  
km
```

Не совсем уверен как правильно, подскажите как это сделать?
Список станций будет загружаться в базу из файла.
Соседние станции будут идти одна за другой после названия линии метро:
к примеру на линии Boock будет такой список:

```
Boock Line (линия)  
Ajax Rapids (соседняя станция)  
HTML Heights (соседняя станция)  
JavaBeans Boulevard (соседняя станция)  
...
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**PS**
т.е. впоследствии будет алгоритм вычисления кратчайшего пути от одной станции к другой.
Но это сейчас не интересует, сейчас интересует как правильно организовать базу данных

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы вряд ли будете просчитывать [кратчайший путь](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BC_%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8) напрямую через SQL, скорее выгружая все станции в память и используя алгоритм в коде.

Поэтому вам удобнее и проще будет иметь простейшую БД с разделением на линии, станции и пересадки.

**Таблица линий**

```
ID Name
1 Booch Line
2 Gamma Line
```

**Таблица станций**

```
ID LineID Name 
1 1 AJAX Rapids
2 1 HTML Heights
```

**Таблица пересадок**

```
LineFromID LineToID StationFromID StationToID
```

В таблице пересадок можно записывать круговые (замкнутые) линии, где значения From/To будут идентичными.

Используя данные таблицы можно будет реализовать отношение между линиями и станциями через belongsTo/hasMany, а для пересадок (Transition) использовать модель с методами для каждой линии и станции с дополнительным методом для проверки на замыкающуюся станцию в круговой ветке:

```
 class Transition extends Eloquent
 {
      protected $fillable = ['line_from_id', 'line_to_id', 'station_from_id', 'station_to_id'];

       public function lineTo()
       {
            return $this->hasOne(Station::class, 'line_to_id');
       }

       public function lineFrom()
       {
            return $this->hasOne(Station::class, 'line_from_id');
       }

       public function isCircular()
       {
            return $this->station_from_id === $this->station_to_id;
       }
 }
```

Кстати, для сохранения расстояний можно использовать таблицу пересадок, но это уже вам вопрос на засыпку как именно ;)

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста, что вы имеете ввиду под методом isCircular() ? какую роль он выполняет в данной задаче? и я так понимаю алгоритм поиска кратчайшего пути через sql не получится реализовать? к примеру алгоритм Дейкстры, т.е. без php

Comment: Алгоритм поиска будет намного быстрее реализовать в PHP так как SQL запросы очень специфичны и вряд ли подойдут для  этого. Вспомогательный isCircular метод позволит узнать если станция замыкается сама на себя (для случаев кольцевых линий). Можно аналогичный метод реализовать у линии, чтобы не хранить тип линии в БД.

Comment: всё-равно не понял этот нюанс. В каком случае Transition может содержать одинаковые station_from_id и station_to_id?  return $this->station_from_id === $this->station_to_id;

Comment: Думаю эту часть можно удалить, я не до конца это продумал.